# Copying the projectname.dll file from my visual studio project to my IIS bin folder is this correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-6, webdeploy

I have created an asp.net mvc web application on staging, then I have created a web deployment package using visual studio for the project and I have copied the generated web deployment .zip file from staging and publish it inside the IIS on production.

And then I did some modification to the Controller & model classes on staging , so instead of re-creating the whole web deployment package from staging to production , I just copied the projectname.dll file which is found inside the bin folder on the visual studio project, and I copied the projectname.dll directly to the bin folder inside the IIS on production. 
Currently everything is working well, but my question is whether copying the .dll file from the bin folder inside the visual studio project to the bin folder inside the IIS , considered valid ?, or it might cause some issues I am not aware of ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is valid, if it is build in `Release` mode and the version is the same(if you have dependencies), it is virtually the same thing.

A deployment package would have done the same thing.